# plm package in R Installation error

Tags: r, plm

I get the following error when I try to install plm package on R 3.1.1 with Windows 7.

```
"Error: package ‘Formula’ required by ‘plm’ could not be found"
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
install.packages("Formula")
```

should work, if the only problem is just that Formula isn't installed. Looks like you could have the same issue with other packages, so you might need to do the same with lattice, bdsmatrix, zoo, and sandwich